# Microsoft Robotics Studio, simple simulation

Tags: robotics, robotics-studio

I am soon to start with Microsoft Robotics Studio.

My question is to all the gurus of MSRS, **Can simple simulation (as obstacle avoidance and wall following) be done without any hardware ?**

Does MSRS have 3-dimensional as well as 2-dimensional rendering? As of now I do not have any hardware and I am only interested in simulation, when I have the robot hardware I may try to interface it!

Sorry for a silly question, I am a MSRS noob, but have previous robotics h/w and s/w experience.

Other than MSRS and Player Project (Player/Stage/Gazebo) is there any other Software to simulate robots, effectively ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MSRS tackles several key areas. One of them is simulation. The 3D engine is based on the AGeia Physics engine and can simulate not only your robot and its sensors, but a somewhat complex environment.

The demo I saw had a Pioneer with a SICK lidar running around a cluttered appartment living room, with tables, chairs and etc.

The idea is that your code doesn't even need to know if it's running on the simulator or the real robot.

**Edit:**
A few links as requested:
Start here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd939184.aspx
[alt text http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/Dd939184.image001(en-us,MSDN.10).jpg](http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/Dd939184.image001(en-us,MSDN.10).jpg)

Then go here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd939190.aspx
[alt text http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/Dd939190.image008(en-us,MSDN.10).jpg](http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/Dd939190.image008(en-us,MSDN.10).jpg)

Then take a look at some more samples: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc998497.aspx
[alt text http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/Cc998496.Sumo1(en-us,MSDN.10).jpg](http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/Cc998496.Sumo1(en-us,MSDN.10).jpg)

Comment: @Padu Merloti : ...... ' code doesn't even need to know if it's running on the simulator or the real robot' .... REALLY ... Then I am for some thrill ride ! ... have you been working on MSRS ? .... Do you have sample program snippets etc ....(a blogspot will sure help a Noob as me ! )

Comment: Terrific, I wanted to vote you up ! .... but this system would not let me do so ! .... Many thanks ... by any chance have you worked with player-stage ?

Comment: I have not, but some of my colleagues from a DoD branch (sorry can't say which) use it and love it to control Segway RMP's

Comment: I have recently got Player Stage to work (and it is for academic stuff, not DoD :D ) .... it is really nice ! .... I wish I could vote you up dude ...

Comment: @Padu Merloti : One more question, I guess Microsoft Robotics Developers Studio is not open-source nor freeware ? .... am I right ?

Comment: According to this site: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/robotics/aa731520.aspx it is free of charge for both commercial and non-commercial endeavors. The main core is not open source, but most examples are.

Comment: @Padu Merloti : Hey, do you know which version of ODE does MRDS uses ?

Answer (score 1):

simple answer is yes, MRDS simulator and player/stage have very similar capabilities. MRDS uses a video game quality physics engine under the hood, so you can do collisions, and some basic physics on your robots, but its not going to be the level of accuracy of a matlab simulation (on the flip side its realtime and easier to develop with though). You can do a lot in MRDS without any hardware.

MRDS uses some pretty advanced programming abstractions, so can be a bit intimidating at first, but do the tutorials, and the course that has been posted to codeplex "software engineering for robotics" and you will be fine. http://swrobotics.codeplex.com/